TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable con archivo de excel importado
En el script de calculo_resistencia básicamente estoy sacando un listado de filas de un archivo excel, con la siguiente forma:
 valores_resistencia_por_fila[i-1] = {'id': id_punto,'valores': valores_resistencia, 'fecha_hora': fecha_hora, 'corriente': valores_corriente, 'voltaje': valores_voltaje}

Yo lo que quiero es que el programa me pida un ID (estilo 120996), yo se lo escriba y me devuelva el valor máximo de corriente, ya que esta se define como: [232, 156, 200, 854, 98]
from calculo_resistencia import  valores_resistencia_por_fila

valor_resistencia_por_fila = []

for elemento in  valores_resistencia_por_fila:
    id_punto = elemento['id']
    valores_resistencia = tuple(elemento['valores'])
    valores_corriente = tuple(elemento['corriente'])
    valores_voltaje = tuple(elemento['voltaje'])

    nuevo_diccionario = {
        'id': id_punto,
        'resistencia': valores_resistencia,
        'corriente': valores_corriente,
        'voltaje': valores_voltaje
    }

    valor_resistencia_por_fila.append(nuevo_diccionario)

print(valor_resistencia_por_fila)


# Función para encontrar el valor máximo de corriente correspondiente a un ID dado
def max_corriente_por_id(id_buscar):
    for fila in valor_resistencia_por_fila:
        if fila['id'] == id_buscar:
            return max(fila['corriente'])
    return None

# Bucle iterativo para pedir al usuario que ingrese el ID
while True:
    id_ingresado = input("Ingresa el ID (o escribe 'pare' para detenerse): ")
    
    # Verificar si el usuario desea detenerse
    if id_ingresado.lower() == 'pare':
        print("¡Deteniendo el programa!")
        break
    
    # Convertir el ID ingresado a entero
    try:
        id_ingresado = int(id_ingresado)
    except ValueError:
        print("Por favor, ingresa un ID válido (número entero) o escribe 'pare' para detenerse.")
        continue
    
    # Encontrar y mostrar el valor máximo de corriente correspondiente al ID ingresado
    valor_max_corriente = max_corriente_por_id(id_ingresado)
    if valor_max_corriente is not None:
        print(f"El valor máximo de corriente para el ID {id_ingresado} es: {valor_max_corriente}")
    else:
        print(f"No se encontró ningún valor de corriente para el ID {id_ingresado}")


¿en qué línea ocurre el error?
